# Prevent wysiwyg source code editor from changing all website

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg, jodit

Im using a WYSIWYG editor (called "Jodit") in my website. it has the functionality to be able to add html code. If I add some html style code along with "!important" I can modify the CSS of my entire website.

Example, go to https://xdsoft.net/jodit/play.html?currentTab=State

Click the "Change Mode" icon ""

Paste in

```
<html>
<style>
    * {
        color:red !important;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

The whole websites text goes red.

How can I stop a wysiwyg editor from modifying code outside of its textarea?

Comment: actually your code is setting the whole site font color to red. !important is telling the browser to ignore any further color modification. This behaviour has nothing to do with the editor. It is pure css and the browser is working as expected. What do you mean with "textarea"?

Comment: That's the point I'm making, the whole site is going red, which is not what I want to happen, I just want the red to be applied to the WYSIWYG editor contents.  Textarea is the html input type, where you see the editor.

Comment: then you have to apply the style only to that textarea and not to the whole site, no?

Comment: sorry there is a little confusion. Im using a wysiwyg editor (Jodit) simiarl to the webpage in the link I provided. The editor would allow people to create emails.

The problem I had, as displayed in the link above, is when I try to add styles to the editor (or the textarea) if I were to use the css flag !important, it would not only modify the css inside the editor/textarea, but also everything outside of that on the main webpage - which I did not want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to make the selector more specific so it only targets content inside the WYSIWYG area, such as

```css
.jodit_workplace > * {
    color: red !important;
}
```

If the content from the WYSIWYG editor is not under your control (for example, if a user can edit and publish it) and you can therefore not prefix the selector, you could use an iframe or [shadow dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) to completely isolate it from the rest of your page.

Comment: This was close. It turns out the editor has an "iframe" flag which stops my issue occuring https://github.com/xdan/jodit/issues/301